# Sed how to add variable with vertical bar to the end of first line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

i want to append variable with string to the first line of `my_file`

`sed -i "1 s/$/   $my_variable/" ~/my_file`

Now i have this:

`42 192.168.1.1   string_from_my_variable`

It works. But the task become harder, now i need to add delimiter before `string_from_my_variable`

I tried to `sed -i "1 s#$#   \|\$my_variable#" ~/my_file`, of course it does not help. I need to have this:

`42 192.168.1.1   | string_from_my_variable`

How can i do this ? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a coincidence in your command `sed -i "1 s#$#   \|\$my_variable#"`, the `$#` is a **special parameter** in the double quotation marks(**""**), which means **the number of parameters are given**, you can get more informations by `man bash`:

> `Special Parameters
>    #      Expands to the number of positional parameters in decimal.`

so, your command is illegal.

```
# $# is a special parameter, so the command is illegal:
$ sed "1s#$#   |${my_variable}#" my_file 
sed: -e expression #1, char 32: unterminated `s' command
# when used ', the special meaning of $# is gone,
# and the command is legal, but doesn't work for your expection:
$ sed '1s#$#   |${my_variable}#' my_file 
42 192.168.1.1   |${my_variable}
# add a space beteween `$#`, and the command is legal too,
# but still doesn't work for your expection:
$ sed "1s#$ #   |${my_variable}#" my_file 
42 192.168.1.1
```

you can use a different delimiter instead of `#`:

```
my_variable="string_from_my_variable"
sed -i "1s/$/   |${my_variable}/" ~/my_file
```

P.S:

1. the `\` before `$my_variable` should NOT exist.
2. the `\` before `|` is unnecessary if the delimiter  is NOT `|`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to deal with literal strings that come from a shell variable, I would go with awk:

```
awk -v extra="$my_variable" 'NR == 1 { $0 = $0 "   |" extra } 1' file
```

Add the extra string to the first line and `1` at the end is the shortest way to write `1 { print $0 }`, so every line gets printed.

To overwrite your original file:

```
# GNU Awk
awk -i inplace -v extra="$my_variable" 'NR == 1 { $0 = $0 "   |" extra } 1' file
# any Awk
awk -v extra="$my_variable" 'NR == 1 { $0 = $0 "   |" extra } 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

i have found:

`sed -i "1 s/$/   \|$my_variable/" ~/my_file`

Comment: Could you add some details? Add an explanation if you developed the code yourself or add a link if you found it elsewhere.